# PyQt: How to scroll to right in a QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, scrollbar, qlistwidget

In a PyQt QListWidget I drag and drop files with their full path. Now I want the scrollbar to scroll to the right everytime I drag something in.
However, there seems to be only `scrollToTop()` and `scrollToBottom()`, but I couldn't find `scrollToLeft()` or `scrollToRight()` or anything similar. Right alignment of the list items' text does not help, apparently I need to scroll the horizontal scrollbar to the right.

How can I automatically scroll to right, such that I see the filenames, *not* the beginning of the path?
It must be a simple setting, but I haven't found helpful documentation or examples so far.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QApplication, QWidget, QAbstractItemView, QVBoxLayout

class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls() or event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(MyListWidget, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                item = QListWidgetItem(url.toLocalFile())
                self.addItem(item)
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        elif event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            self.addItem(event.mimeData().text())
        else:
            super(myListWidget,self).dropEvent(event)
        self.scrollToBottom()                            ### but I want scrollToRight()  !!! 
        

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 50 
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lw_myList = MyListWidget(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lw_myList)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # app.setStyle("plastique")
    window = MyWindow()
    # window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatical scrolling of all widgets that inherit from QAbstractScrollArea can be achieved (and should *only* be done) by setting the value of its scrollbars (even if they are not visible).

Since item views like QListWidget (which inherits from QListView and QAbstractItemView) need some *time* in order to correctly lay out new items, it's usually preferred to call [`QCoreApplication.processEvents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) and, just to be safe, [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries):

```
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # ...

        # ensure that the event queue is correctly processed, which includes
        # laying out new items
        QApplication.processEvents()
        # ensure that the geometry of child widgets is correctly updated too
        self.updateGeometries()
        # finally, set the horizontal scroll bar to its maximum
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())
```

You can even provide a "monkey patched" function for all item views, by putting this at the beginning of the *first* script that imports QtWidgets:

```
def itemViewScrollToRight(self):
    QApplication.processEvents()
    self.updateGeometries()
    self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(
        self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())

QAbstractItemView.scrollToRight = itemViewScrollToRight

# ...
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # ...
        self.scrollToRight()
```

PS: note that you should always implement `dragMoveEvent()` and accept the event for custom drag implementations, as `dragEnterEvent()` doesn't always suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works fine! To see the end (i.e. the filenames) of different long paths, of course, I additionally need to right align the text of the items `item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)`.